# Is there any way to know whether a form has been minimized?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I am trying to find out if my winform has been minimized or not.

I can't use property `FormWindowState.Minimized` for this purpose. Let's just say that this property isn't working for me.

Can I use Out of focus or form deactivated event to know that the form is minimized? As far as I know there are no event raised when a form is minimized.

Comment: *Let's just say that this property isn't working for me* - please provide a reason for this, since this is the *only* (recommended) way...

Comment: I haven't still figured out why 'FormWindowState.Minimized' is not working for me, I am just trying to find a work around for this problem. Is there any other way?

Comment: I think a better approach would be to try and understand why `FormWindowState.Minimized'` is not working, instead of looking for a work-around... Post your code and provide a [mcve] and I am sure people would love to help you out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't use property FormWindowState.Minimized for this purpose

This is indeed the property you should use for that purpose.

> Can I use Out of focus or form deactivated event to know that the form is minimized? As far as I know there are no event raised when a form is minimized.

When the form is minimized, the [SizeChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.sizechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event is fired. For instance, try the following:

```
// Inside the form constructor or load event
this.SizeChanged += Form_SizeChanged;

private void Form_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        MessageBox.Show("I'm minimized.");
}
```

Comment: SizeChanged event should work but it will get fired every time I change my form size also.

Comment: Indeed. But you will ignore the other calls and just check the WindowState.Minimized. You could track WindowState property change, but it doesn't make sense since SizeChanged is fired only once when your form is minimized.